# Vote can't be changed if answer is edited too quickly

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, edits, voting, locked-votes

I've looked through a number of the "Vote too old to be changed" questions, but I think this one's different.

I gave a downvote to an answer I thought had a critical defect, and I left a comment describing the defect. The answer was edited to satisfy my criticism, but it was done within the short grace period where edits aren't recorded as such. When I try to cancel my downvote I get the error - "Your vote is now locked in unless this answer is edited" - but **it was edited!**

In reference to this answer: [How to generate different random numbers in a loop in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4926622/how-to-generate-different-random-number-in-a-loop-in-c/4926646#4926646)

Comment: Hmm, what a delightful edge case

Comment: Grace period edit is not a "real" edit, as it does not create a new revision and can't be tracked. By all means, such edit is still part of the original revision edited during grace period. So, not a bug.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Whether its a bug or not is really semantics. Its certainly undesired behaviour. Buggy-by-design at best

Comment: @Richard fear we'll have to disagree about it, you can start new feature request asking to change the current design. With Jeff gone, it got a chance to at least be considered.

Comment: @ShadowWizard not if it gets closed as a duplicate instantly

Comment: @JanDvorak I'll vote to reopen since this one here is a bug report.

Comment: @ShadowWizard thanks :-) Hope it finally gets fixed

Comment: @Jan well, I got a different opinion but won't stand in its way. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard actually, I'd prefer to get rid of vote locking entirely, but the dev team is afraid of strategic voting.

Comment: What does it take to get this fixed?

Comment: @shmosel a tag of `status-bydesign` means that they've looked at it and decided they don't consider it a bug, so it will *never* be fixed. Now this question is old enough that it could be reconsidered, but they don't have a mechanism for that. I don't have any answers.

Comment: FYI, since 2015, commenting on someone else's post will now break the grace period, making the specific problem here a non-issue. There's still the edge case of votes changing if there's no comment posted, though.

Answer (score 6):

This is indeed a very annoying bug which I experienced myself a few times.

The proposed solution by Richard doesn't really look like an answer to me, it's just a workaround (no offense to Richard, this is the only possible solution right now). Secondly, it will reveal the one reverting his vote since his name is on the edit.

The solution seems to me to register internally whether the question / answer was edited during the grace period and allow voting afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

Just edit the answer yourself, then roll it back...

Comment: That doesn't eliminate the bug, it's just a work-around. Very sneaky though, if it works.

Comment: @Mark It works. I've done it several times for this same problem.

Comment: For now I'm going to leave it just in case the SO crew wants to have a look at the current status.

Comment: @Mark no argument with that. Just presenting the current workaround

Answer (score -11):

This is by design -- edits in the 5 minute grace period are treated as if the post always existed that way.

Comment: I know the 5 minute grace period is by design, and I've taken advantage of it many times; thank you. But can I assume the bug is **not** by design? If you were to classify it as *not worth fixing* I'd understand.

Comment: @mark it's not a bug, it's by design. I recommend not voting on anything only a few minutes old as it might change underneath you.

Comment: I know you're not around any more to see this, but I had a thought I wanted to record. Your advice is impractical because I want to vote as early as possible, so it will influence others considering the answer in its current form.

Comment: If this is by design than the design is buggy.

Comment: Luckily this post is older than 5 mins, so I can downvote without the risk that Jeff edits it to something sensible underneath me.