# Vote "locked in" despite edit

Tags: bug, voting, locked-votes

I downvoted [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16626812/211627) because I disagreed with part of the explanation. The OP edited the answer to remove the confusing language. When I attempted to remove my downvoted, I got a popup saying my vote was locked in unless the answer is edited.

Does an edit need to occur *after* the vote has been locked? I would think that an edit would prevent the vote from being locked in the first place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks as if the post was edited during the grace period, there are [no edit revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/16626812/revisions) listed for that post.

You have enough rep to freely edit the post. You could make a trivial edit just to unlock the vote. Roll back the edit if you feel the trivial edit was otherwise not needed.

See [Vote can't be changed if answer is edited too quickly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78442/vote-cant-be-changed-if-answer-is-edited-too-quickly) for a bug report on the issue; it was declined as [status-by-design](/questions/tagged/status-by-design).