# What can be done against abuse of edits?

Tags: discussion, edits, abuse

Today I saw that someone revised one of my answers, but at first I couldn't see any changes.
After switching to `side-by-side markdown` I saw that he only adds a single space at the end.

Therefore I examined the activity/revisions of the user and saw that he edits hundreds or thousands  of posts in this way.

I had hoped, that this sort of abuse should be detected by some automatism, but there seems no such system.

But how to stop users like him and what can be done to detect this before so many posts are changed without any good reason?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196219/automatically-detect-edit-abuse-and-exclude-from-badges-flag-for-mod-review

Comment: My first thought would be that they're trying to reverse a vote, but doing that to hundreds of posts does sound suspicious.

Comment: @Matt Yes, it's even the user I thought of!