# X reviews per minute flag

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review

I don't want to call out any specific users, as I would rather "[discuss actions not users, behaviors not people](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/197072/217863)" but I've come across a few users who seem to do reviews at an alarming rate...

Perhaps I'm a little slower than the average reviewer, but it seems to me, that averaging 6-12 reviews per-minute makes for pretty obvious evidence of robo-reviewing or at least questionable review quality.

Would it be worth it to put together an automated flag that simply looks at the number of reviews per-minute and if that rate exceeds X reviews per minute bring it to a moderator's attention?

Comment: 6-12 reviews per *minute*? I go through comment flags faster than that. 6 reviews in 10 seconds is a bit more alarming.

Comment: I suggested [something similar](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/196219/191410), though for edits, not specifically reviews.

Comment: I think something like this already exists in the mod toolbox, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @animuson but *comments are second-class citizens* anyway, right? ;) And are usually way shorter than answers or questions, and way simpler to judge.

Comment: @animuson We do want reviewers to actually read the posts they're reviewing right? Less than 10 seconds per post seems a little fast to both read and appropriately respond. Comment flags are another matter, comments are usually only a few sentences at best...

Comment: @apaul34208 My AvgDuration for Low Quality Posts is currently 9.4 seconds.

Comment: @animuson low quality posts are another case where you're usually looking at 1 or 2 sentences. What's your average on close votes or suggested edits?

Comment: @apaul34208 12.3 over 8 reviews...That one's not very helpful. I'll spend a day in a few queues and see what I end up at. Moderators don't really have very good stats in the review queues.

Comment: @animuson I suppose it is possible for some users to be both quick and accurate, but I would guess that, that is the exception rather than the rule. That's part of the reason I suggested an auto flag rather than a rate limit.

Comment: One might want to consider the *types* of closures.  Off topic - "minimal understanding", "describe the problem", and "recommend or find a tool" ones may go quite fast as they can be easy to spot. Other ones where there's a good question at the core and need to be duped or need a custom off topic may take a bit more time.

Comment: @MichaelT - Or we could just adjust the "flow-rate" flag to be a bit more universal. If a 10 second flow-rate produces too many false-positives, reduce it to 8 or 6, etc.

Comment: @MichaelT That is also a very useful indicator. I normally filter by "off-topic" only when I review in the Close Votes queue and fly through them.

Comment: @animuson - Wouldn't that be easy to beat/hard to query, though? A user could just not apply a filter and then vote to close everything as off-topic. Or how would you measure the flow-rate for someone who just reviews whatever comes next (no filter)?

Comment: @animuson: is there anything that detects if the suggested duplicate is not looked at for close reviews?

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy I don't think you can close as a dup. without the original popping up in the close dialog. Granted some may not take the time to read it, but it does show it to them.

Comment: @apaul34208: ah yes, I was thinking of the tabs up the top.