# Grace period edits will still lock in votes

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, edits, voting, grace-period

The usual rule is if I vote, it's locked in after 5 minutes or something, unless the question is edited. However, it seems if the edit takes place in a grace period of posting a question or the last edit, my vote is still locked in. This seems buggy.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Vote can't be changed if answer is edited too quickly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78442/vote-cant-be-changed-if-answer-is-edited-too-quickly) and [Quick edit not recorded as such blocking vote change](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/150002/quick-edit-not-recorded-as-such-blocking-vote-change) and [Unlock votes if post is edited during the grace period](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168553/unlock-votes-if-post-is-edited-during-the-grace-period)

Comment: @animuson thanks. I'm bad at searching for these on meta

Comment: Dude. This isn't by design. wtf. just admit it's a bug.